# Azure Mobile Services Query return undefined

Tags: javascript, azure-mobile-services

I have an application, that when a user login I retrieve all necessary data to the app using Javascript Back-End.
But, when running a query, I got the result undefined! But there are rows in the table!
Here is my Javascript code query:

```
function getClientTanks(clientName) {
    var clientTanksTable = tables.getTable("ClientsTanks");
    var tanks = [];

    clientTanksTable
    .where(function(currentClientId){
        return this.idclient == currentClientId;
    }, clientName).read({
        success: function(results) {
                //Here my results parameter is Undefined
                if (results.length === 0) {
                    console.log("No client tank");                    
                }
                else {
                    //My code got here, but my results are undefined,
                    //So I have no rows to work with, 
                    //but exist rows in the table I'm querying                  
                }
            }
    });    
}
```

Here is a print of my table with the rows:

[image]

Also, when I write `“Console.log(value)”` inside the anonymous function in the `where` I receive a Server error 500.
To give more information, I already tried to do the where with an object as parameter instead a function, like this:

`.where({idclient : clientName})`

Did anyone have this problem? And if did. Now how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: First glance it seems ok, if you hit the table API with the filter directly does it return results as you expect?  i.e. /tables/clientstanks?$filter=idclient eq 'ClienteTeste2'  Is anything added to your logs tab?

Comment: I did a test with Postman and it worked:

'`https://arduinoapp.azure-mobile.net/tables/ClientsTanks?$filter=idclient%20eq%20'ClienteTeste2'`

u.u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem and was a silly error.

When I prepared the code to post here in StackOverflow, without notice, I corrected my mistake.

In my code, I was getting the wrong table name. Instead of "ClientsTanks" I typed "ClientTanks".

Sorry for the question, now I see it's time to cover with tests my Javascript and also to pay attention to details.